# brew 0.1.4 installation for python pip error

Tags: python, pip

I'm new to python and i have been trying to install brew 0.1.4. I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\sys>pip install brew
Collecting brew
Using cached brew-0.1.4.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\sys\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m49ufx8l\brew\setup.py",line 22, in <module>
with open('requirements.txt') as fid:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'requirements.txt'

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\sys\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m49ufx8l\brew\
```

I have tried the freeze method to create the requirements file but still get the same error. Help me resolve this.

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requirements.txt` seems to be missing in the .zip file from pypi. Try installing from the github repository instead:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/viisar/brew.git
```